# Android animation crashes when starting

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to play an animation but cant get it to work...
When I start the application on my phone it just crashes and restarts, I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

**xml for the imageView:**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAnimation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

**xml for the animation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka1"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka2"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka3"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka4"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka5"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka6"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka7"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka8"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka9"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka10"
        android:duration="200"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/figur_vinka11"
        android:duration="200"/>

</animation-list>
```

**and the java code where I'm trying to play the animation:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class hejda extends Activity {
    private AnimationDrawable HejDa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hejda_skarm);
        ImageView hejda = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAnimation);
        hejda.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.hejda);

        HejDa = (AnimationDrawable) hejda.getBackground();
        Animation();
    }

    private void Animation() {
        HejDa.start();

    }
}
```

**logcat:**

```
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722): Writing exception to parcel
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722):     at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722):     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
05-28 00:52:47.499: E/DatabaseUtils(28722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-28 00:52:48.464: E/dalvikvm-heap(5737): Out of memory on a 2560016-byte allocation.
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:873)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2970)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15697)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at com.TomasO.blandaochmala.hejda.onCreate(hejda.java:18)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-28 00:52:48.469: E/AndroidRuntime(5737):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 00:52:48.499: A/libc(5778): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x00001692 (code=0), thread 5778 (uptime)
05-28 00:52:48.779: E/android.os.Debug(28722): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
05-28 00:52:50.069: A/libc(5780): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x00001694 (code=0), thread 5780 (top)
05-28 00:52:50.414: A/libc(5783): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x00001697 (code=0), thread 5783 (ps)
05-28 00:52:50.714: A/libc(5785): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x00001699 (code=0), thread 5785 (ps)
05-28 00:52:51.299: A/libc(5789): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x0000169d (code=0), thread 5789 (logcat)
05-28 00:52:51.504: A/libc(5791): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x0000169f (code=0), thread 5791 (logcat)
05-28 00:52:51.704: A/libc(5793): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x000016a1 (code=0), thread 5793 (logcat)
05-28 00:52:52.214: A/libc(5798): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x000016a6 (code=0), thread 5798 (ip)
05-28 00:52:52.409: A/libc(5800): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x000016a8 (code=0), thread 5800 (ip)
05-28 00:52:52.614: A/libc(5803): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x000016ab (code=0), thread 5803 (ip)
05-28 00:52:52.914: A/libc(5806): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x000016ae (code=0), thread 5806 (ip)
05-28 00:52:54.929: A/libc(5827): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x000016c3 (code=0), thread 5827 (df)
05-28 00:52:58.404: E/ViewRootImpl(28722): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-28 00:52:58.424: E/InputDispatcher(28722): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-28 00:52:58.424: E/InputDispatcher(28722): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-28 00:52:58.994: E/(5835): Device driver API match
05-28 00:52:58.994: E/(5835): Device driver API version: 23
05-28 00:52:58.994: E/(5835): User space API version: 23 
05-28 00:52:58.994: E/(5835): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57 KST 2013 
05-28 00:52:59.049: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(28722): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
```

Comment: Can you please add logcat output?

Comment: It sems I even cant create the animation.. i tried just to create it but not starting it but no luck.. if comment out the create I will se the layout etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the images could be too large for the device. Try smaller images with just two drawables and see if it displays. If not, it's definitely a code problem.

Comment: ok the images i 600x600, i have used 700x700 on other images(not for animation) before.. but i will try

Comment: Yes I'm not 100% but I would imagine all 12 600x600 images are loaded into RAM and it's too costly, therefore you get the out of memory error

Comment: Yes this worked! thx, i tought that a image that is 173kb could not be the problem.. well im a n00b at this :)

Comment: Great! Read more here if you are interested: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html but best to either cut the image dimensions down substantially or have far less

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.lib.MainActivity"
    android:label="LibMain" 
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Or

```
<provider     
android:name="com.identifier.gamecenterapp.contentprovider.MyGamesContentProvider"
android:authorities="com.identifier.gamecenterapp.contentprovider"       
android:exported="true">
</provider>

<uses-permission android:name="com.identifier.gamecenterapp.contentprovider.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.identifier.gamecenterapp.contentprovider.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
```